# Positioning with HTML and css

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="pageHeading">
    <h1>zisland</h1>
    <img src="islandpic.jpg" alt="Mountain View"  style="width:50px;height:50px">
</div>

#pageHeading{
    color: #000000;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #800080;
}
```

The image of the island appears to be centered below the text "zisland". My question is, how do i get the image of the island to be positioned to the right of the text "zisland" instead of being below?

Answer (score 1):

Use `float: right` on the `<img>` tag, or `float: left` on `<h1>`.

```
<div id="pageHeading">
    <h1>zisland</h1>
    <img src="islandpic.jpg" alt="Mountain View">
</div>

#pageHeading {
    color: #000000;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #800080;
}

#pageHeading h1 {
    float: left;
}

#pageHeading img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You may want following this:** here, given two options.

```css
#pageHeading {

  color: #000000;

  width: auto;

  height: auto;

  text-align: center;

  background-color: #800080;

}

#pageHeading h1,

#pageHeading img {

  display: inline-flex;

  margin: 0;

}


#pageHeading1 {
  background-color: #800080;
  color: #000000;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
}
#pageHeading1 h1 {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 0;
}
#pageHeading1 img {
  float: right;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="pageHeading">
  <h1>zisland</h1>
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8a/Alouette-iii-boven-berggebied.jpg/300px-Alouette-iii-boven-berggebied.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:50px;height:50px">
</div>
<br/><br/><br/>
<div id="pageHeading1">
  <h1>zisland</h1>
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8a/Alouette-iii-boven-berggebied.jpg/300px-Alouette-iii-boven-berggebied.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:50px;height:50px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use display:inline-block; prop for img and h1 tag

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m00xz3as/)

**CSS Code**

```
#pageHeading, h1, img
{
    display:inline-block;
}
```